# Tigger.io accessing device sqlite db

Tags: javascript, sqlite, trigger.io

Is there any example of js accessing device's (ios and android) sqlite db via Trigger.io?

Answer (score 2):

The normal web database API is available: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

**Note**: not all browsers support Web SQL http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

For example, one of the tests we run is similar to this:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'example database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');  
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE foo');

    // known to fail - so should rollback the DROP statement
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
    forge.logging.error("INSERT into non-existent table succeeded!");
}, function (err) {
    forge.logging.info("error callback invoked, as expected");
});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo', [], function (tx, results) {
        forge.logging.info("row: "+results);
    });
});
```

Comment: The specification marked as depricated. Are there any other ways?

Comment: IndexedDB will be the replacement: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ but it hasn't made it into stock mobile browsers yet: http://caniuse.com/indexeddb

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use something like [LocalForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) as this fallsback through indexedDB to webSQL to localStorage for you, plus gives you a consistent api. And if you are using Angular/Ionic then this is the business: [Angular-LocalForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)